# For the filter: Invalid date (Valid date format D/MM/YYYY)

Tags: formula, reporting, custom-field, dashboard, custom-reports

Our report does not work when we add a formula(Date) field on the report filters and whose value is set to a relative date such as CURRENT FISCAL YEAR. The error is:

> For the filter 3: Invalid date (Valid date format 9/22/2023)

[image]

[image]

This looks like a bug to me...

Comment: Take a look at the documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.filter_dates_relative.htm&type=5